# In .NET Maui, how to reset the selected radiobutton in a CollectionView.ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, maui

I have this set of Radio buttons created via an ItemTemplate. I want to reset which radio button is currently selected when I click the button. Please help me understand where in the MVVM architecture the information about which radio button is currently selected is hidden when I use an ItemTemplate. And how to remove said selection.

I have the NuGet CommunityToolkit.Mvvm installed and have made a github repository with all the code below: https://github.com/jacobfredsoee/ItemTemplateResetHelp

MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ItemTemplateReset.View.MainPage"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ItemTemplateReset.Model">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="20">
            <Label Text="Role type:"/>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding PickableRoles}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:PickableRole">
                            <RadioButton Content="{Binding Name}" 
                                            Value="{Binding Id}"
                                            CheckedChanged="OnRoleChange"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </VerticalStackLayout>

            <Label Text="{Binding SelectedRole, StringFormat='Selected Role: {0}'}" x:Name="SelectedRole"/>

            <Button
                x:Name="ResetButton"
                Text="Click me to reset"
                Clicked="OnResetClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

The CodeBehind, MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace ItemTemplateReset.View;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    MainPageViewModel viewModel;
    public MainPage(MainPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    private void OnResetClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //How to reset the radio buttons so that none is selected?
        viewModel.SelectedRole = -1; //This does not work
    }

    private void OnRoleChange(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e) {
        RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
        viewModel.SelectedRole = int.Parse(rb.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

The ViewModel, MainPageViewModel.cs:

```
namespace ItemTemplateReset.ViewModel;

public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<PickableRole> PickableRoles { get; set; } = new();

    [ObservableProperty]
    public int selectedRole = -1;

    public MainPageViewModel() {
        SetPickableRoles();
    }

    private void SetPickableRoles() {
        PickableRoles.Add(new PickableRole() { Id = 1, Name = "Role 1"} );
        PickableRoles.Add(new PickableRole() { Id = 2, Name = "Role 2" });
        PickableRoles.Add(new PickableRole() { Id = 3, Name = "Role 3" });
        PickableRoles.Add(new PickableRole() { Id = 4, Name = "Role 4" });
        PickableRoles.Add(new PickableRole() { Id = 5, Name = "Role 5" });
    }
}
```

And finally, the model, PickableRole.cs

```
namespace ItemTemplateReset.Model;

public class PickableRole
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `SelectedProperty` to your model

```
public partial class PickableRole : ObservableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool selected;
}
```

then bind each `RadioButtoon` to it

```
<RadioButton Content="{Binding Name}" 
         Value="{Binding Id}"
         IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" />
```

then add a method to your VM

```
public void ResetRoles()
{
    foreach(var pr in PickableRoles)
    {
        pr.Selected = false;
    }
}
```

that is called from your button handler

```
private void OnResetClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    viewModel.ResetRoles();
}
```

you can also bind the `RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue` property to your VM, which would eliminate the need for the event handler on each `RadioButton`

Comment: That works, thank you. However, can you explain how to do bind the `RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue`  to the VM? For some reason, I have a hard time wrapping my head around how to do stuff properly in MVVM.